# How do we interpret these lines from 'Ulysses'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry

What do these lines from *Ulysses,* by Tennyson, mean exactly? What is a *sinking* star? How does the simile work in the first line? [This](https://www.shmoop.com/ulysses-tennyson/lines-24-38-summary.html) summary calls the phrase *ambiguous*.

> To follow knowledge like a sinking star,
>
> Beyond the utmost bound of human thought.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is Literary Criticism, not standard English usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is Lit Crit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It refers to a star falling below the horizon, still present but which cannot be followed in plain sight.

Quite how one follows knowledge when it is beyond being thought about is rather more obscure. It's why literary criticism is off-topic, and I'm not going to attempt to analyse Joyce. Or even Tennyson.

Comment: I think it's Ulysses by Alfred, Lord Tennyson

Comment: @deecemobile OK. Whatever. I'm not doing him either :-)

Comment: haha it's all ambiguous

Answer (score 3):

The main ambiguity, for me, lies in that this could be either a positive or negative reference for seeking knowledge.

A "sinking star" also has two possible meanings, so there's more ambiguity.

A falling star/meteor/shooting star is a brief flash, then disappears. Seeking it is pretty much guaranteed to be fruitless.

A star that sinks below the horizon is also something that can be followed, and this one suggests excitement and adventure and huge rewards. Think "second star on the left, and carry on til morning!", or the Wise Men's following of the Star in the East. But ambiguously, it also suggests fruitlessness: you can go around the earth any number of times and you'll never reach that star!

Either way, it seems to say that the pursuit of all knowledge is ultimately unattainable, for "Beyond the utmost bound of human thought" is somewhere that cannot ever be reached by a human, a boundary forever receding.

But, is the quest to push back that boundary a noble and worthy one, or a naïve and foolish one? The quote leaves this unclear, and therein lies the ambiguity.

[Edit: there's also the contrast to the term "rising star", though I don't know if that was in common use at the time: but that contrast implies fading glory.]

Answer (score 0):

To me, 'to follow knowledge like a sinking star' entails 'following' knowledge even if that knowledge is far away like a 'sinking star' is far off. This idea is further cemented by the following line where the word 'bounds' appears. So the idea seems to be that the protagonist wishes to follow knowledge, however distant and challenging it might be, and go beyond the known limit or boundary of it.

Answer (score 0):

"to follow knowledge like a sinking star" a simile, comparing knowledge to a sinking star....However, when the star sink, either in water or land it becomes crystallized. Let knowledge get crystallized to transfigured, transformed and eventually  transcend from being all too human. There is no limit to perception "beyond the utmost bound of human thought.